# How to create a button that shows a randomly generated number on the form?

Tags: vb.net

What I'm trying to do is make a windows form that generates a number and displays it on the form, maybe as a label or whatnot, but not in a text box. the code I have for the button to generate a number is

```
dim rndnumber As Random
dim number As Integer
rndnumber = New Random
number = rndnumber.Next(100, 999)
```

I want to incorporate this with some type of display that isn't a text box, like a label or an image or what have you, but Ive been able to come up with nothing.

Comment: Add a label to your form, then after your randomizing code do (assuming Label1 is the label's name): `Label1.Text = number.ToString()` - it's as simple as that.

Comment: Also, VB6 is not the same as VB.NET. You should remove the tag for the language you're not using (this looks like VB.NET to me, but I am not certain of it).

Comment: If you want to use the Random class then you should seed it with something or you'll get the same random numbers. Try seeding with a newly generated GUID.

Comment: @MichaelZ. : He'll only get the same if done in a no-delay loop. On initialization the seed will, if not specified, be set to the current tick count. **EDIT:** See the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,5d22f8880fc9f8d9).

Comment: @VisualVincent thanks, I had forgotten about that. Still though, if you want good random numbers you won't use the clock either. I guess that may only apply cryptography and other areas where randomization is critical.

Comment: @MichaelZ. : True.

Comment: You only get the same numbers if you **create** a New Random in a loop and use it.  The default seed is already a bit arbitrary. MSDN says the use they "system clock" for the seed, but what that means is the number of milliseconds since you last rebooted. @VisualVincent ...cant ping 2, had to choose

Comment: @Plutonix : Also true, and that I'd forgot :). _But it isn't using the number of milliseconds, but the number of ticks. See my reference source link above._ **EDIT:** No, you were right again. Just read the documentation for `TickCount`. They should've chosen a better name for it.

Comment: See [Environment.TickCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount(v=vs.110).aspx)  It is poorly named and everybody assumes what it is from the name @VisualVincent

Comment: @Plutonix : Already did, just edited my comment. And of course one assume what it is by its name. Why would Microsoft lie to us? ;)

Comment: Wow, thank you all so much for the answers! this has all been very helpful! and to be honest I'm not really worried about the consistency of the randomization of the numbers, so I'm not worried about seeding for different results, as I am really just using the RNG code to kind of test how my interface of my program will look when I fully build it.

Answer (score 0):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2(v=vs.90).aspx

Provided a upper bound and a lower bound this can generate a random number between them. Then the text of a label/what have you can changed to that randomly generated value.

```
    Dim Upper As Long = 12341234
    Dim Lower As Long = 1
    Dim randomvalue = CInt(Math.Floor((Upper - Lower + 1) * Rnd())) + Lower
    label.Text = randomvalue
```

Comment: Why would you create a new randomizing method when he already has one? The one he's using is better, more readable, and optimized for the .NET languages.

Comment: Also, this random method is not good because it is not really random. It will always create the same random numbers. For instance, run the app and press the button. Close the app and reopen it and press the button...same number both times.